# how to debug "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Tags: rigging

I am having this very simple Rig and Character but I keep getting this error message. It is just a single object, has no dub vertices and all transforms are applied.
How can I further debug this? any advice?
[image]

Comment: it may be because the object is too small and Blender struggles to calculate, in that case scale up both the armature and the object and try again, if it doesn't work please share your file

Comment: with the 3D Print Toolbox add-on that comes with Blender, you can check the mesh for intersections/overlapping faces. In edit mode, it can select these faces for you. Another way to find the area with the error you can duplicate the mesh, delete half (or parts) of it and try to bind it to the armature.

Comment: I vitally scaled up up already. As a next step I reduced polys and retopoed. After that it worked. It’s still a bit frustrating to not be able to track the problem down

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when there's intersecting geometry that has inverted faces. Please turn on the "face orientation" from viewport overlays. Go inside the object and try to clear (delete) or invert normal faces (shift+n> invert faces), whenever you find red faces. They all should be blue to the exterior "outside" part of your mesh, not red.
Last, but not least, you need 1 single mesh "clean" topology. If you previously merged "double sided faces" (coplanar planes separated), floating vertices (vertex points near each other, but they are not "merged by distance" (use F3>merge by distance), in your mesh, you will get this kind of trouble.

This is your basic run down list to check out solutions for the failed heat bone weights.